# How to get tap event inside absorb pointer

Tags: flutter

I have a page containing many widgets which is opened in view only mode. i used AbsorbPointer for ignoring user inputs. but in some cases i have to get onTap event on one button which is inside AbsorbPointer. how can i achieve that ?

I tried using GestureDetector but its not giving onTap event.

any idea??

```
 AbsorbPointer(
            absorbing:true,
            child: Column(children: [
            Text("HELLO"),
              Text("HELLO 2"),
              GestureDetector(
                                    onTap: () {
                                      showToast("I tried this");
                                    },
                                    child: IconButton(
                                      icon: Icon(
                                        Icons.local_offer,
                                        color: Colors.red,
                                      ),
                                      onPressed: () {
                                        print("I need this event");
                                      },
                                    ),
                                  )
            ]),
          );
```

Comment: I wrapped `MyWidget` with `AbsorbPointer` then set to true. After that i Wrapped that all with `GestureDetector`. It work, i can detect click inside onTap from `GestureDetector`.

Answer (score 0):

use `absorbing:` property for your cases... set it to `false` in the case you want to allow the `GestureDetector` inside

Comment: i want only that widget to detect Gesture and disable all other widgets in that page. according to your answer it should allow every widget to detect gesture (tap, long press etc).